# How to use the <img> tag to display images not stored in a file? (see description)

Tags: java, database, jsp

I want to display images from a database using an  tag in JSP. How would I be able to use the BLOBs in the  tag? (or is it even possible for that matter? If not, is there a way to use the BLOBs for some meaningful purpose?)

This is the code that I have from a servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    List<Blob> blobList = new ArrayList<Blob>();
    String id = request.getParameter("id");

    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","username","password");
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ICON FROM IMAGES WHERE IMG_NAME=" + id);

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++) {

            blobList.add(rs.getBlob(i));

        }


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: You asked the same question one hour ago, and it was closed already. Don't ask the same question again and again. Read the answer to the already answered identical question.

Comment: @JBNizet I've already looked at that answer and it doesn't answer my question. I'm asking if you can use <img> tags to take blobs and display them. Please reopen this.

Comment: The answer explains it. An `<img>` tag doesn't have a blob attribute. It has an src attribute which must contain a URL. The browser makes an additional request to this URL to download the image. The only alternative is to use a data URI in the src tag, which contains the base64 encoded image, as the answer you got to this question tells you. Googling links to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 0):

You can base64-encode the image and use the result in a "data URI" (Google is your friend here).